# Why function keyword not required on object definition?

Tags: javascript

When using pure javascript I have noticed that some people will code their objects to be defined like this:

```
var oddObject = {
    someProperty: 'random1',

  // NOTE: No function keyword. Why does this work and are there
  //       other places this is also not required?
  someFunction() { return "boring value"; },
  someOtherProperty: 'random2'
}

var el = document.getElementById("result");
el.innerHTML = oddObject.someFunction();
```

I made a fiddle in case you actually want to see that it [does work](https://jsfiddle.net/7p0hm6je/) (at least as of Chrome 47). So why is this allowed and are there other places I can take advantage to abbreviate?

Comment: It's syntactic sugar, e.g., http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/03/es6-and-method-definitions.html

Comment: _Starting with ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced_ ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions))

Comment: So would this not be recommended *yet* unless I am using babel or another transpiler?

Comment: Depends on what you need to target, I guess.

Comment: [You can see what platforms support newer features here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was added in ES2015. In the [ES2015 Object Initializer syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer), we see the *PropertyDefinition* in an object literal can be one of:

> *PropertyDefinition* :
>
> - *IdentifierReference*
> - *CoverInitializedName*
> - *PropertyName* : *AssignmentExpression*
> - ***MethodDefinition***

Where MethodDefinition is one of:

> *MethodDefinition* :
>
> - ***PropertyName* ( *StrictFormalParameters* ) { *FunctionBody* }**
> - *GeneratorMethod*
> - get *PropertyName* ( ) { *FunctionBody* }
> - set *PropertyName* ( *PropertySetParameterList* ) { *FunctionBody* }

By contrast, the [previous ES5 spec's Object Intializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) only allowed normal name/value pairs and `set`/`get` functions:

> *PropertyAssignment* :
>
> - *PropertyName* : *AssignmentExpression*
> - get *PropertyName* ( ) { *FunctionBody* }
> - set *PropertyName* ( *PropertySetParameterList* ) { *FunctionBody* }

Since ES2015 was only recently finalized, this may not be widely implemented yet. (There's a compatibility table on [kangax.github.io](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_methods).)

Note that ES2015 grammar also adds *IdentifierReference* as a valid property, allows you to include a variable's value in an object by including its name in an object literal:

```
var foo = "bar";
var obj = {
    baz: 3,
    foo
};
```

This standalone `foo` property acts the same as the property definition `foo: "bar"`.